# Removing Empty Space of The Background Image in Android Layout

Tags: android, background-image

hi im a newby in android developing and i faced a big problem that i can not fix by myself.
The problem is setting background in my XML file but there is an empty margin in up,down,and both sides so the background picture does not fill the screen fully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    (...)

</LinearLayout>
```

this is what i coded for the background (background file name is 'background'.)
in the code, I have added android:padding, and android:layout_margin but had no effect.
I also tried to increase the size of background picture itself but it only changes the ratio of it but does not fill the screen. what should i do?

p.s. there is no any empty space in the image file itself.

Comment: If you do not wanting empty space, then why add padding?

Comment: Is this your complete xml, or you are adding this xml to somewhere else?

Comment: The padding does not affect background,but if you added margin it's true,the linearlayout size would change and seems background does not fit the linearlayout.

Comment: I thought that if i set a negative value at padding, (like android:padding="-20dp") the image will bigger.

Comment: I'm going to add this xml to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



</LinearLayout>
```

don't add padding and margin in your layout.
and make sure that your background image perfect. means no space on bottom and top [check this for more info](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/).

if you want your app in full screen then use below code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm sure that there is no any space at the image file itself.

Comment: use scrollview with image as background

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
**android:background="@drawable/background"**
use 
android:src="@drawable/background"
may this help you

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work... the background image disappears.